# Get corresponding value in an object with an id

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I have an object that looks like this:

```
var cities = {

      "LA": [
         {id:1, description:"This is a test"},
         {id:3, description:"This is a third test"},
      ],

      "Chicago": [
         {id:2, description:"This is another test"}
      ],

      "Vegas": [
         {id:4, description:"This is another test"},
         {id:5, description:"This is a fifth test"},
         {id:6, description:"This is the last test"},
      ]
}
```

Given an id I want to find the corresponding description.

So for instance, if I was given `id 1` I would want to return `this is a test`. If I was given `id 5` it would return `This is a fifth test`

Does anyone know how this can be done, using vanilla js, or else by using lodash or underscore?

Comment: What specifically are you having problems with? Do you know how to iterate over arrays and objects?

Comment: It's not a good structure for this. If you would want to do this repeatedly, I'd just make a lookup object.

Comment: @Amadan the object is being returned from an API call. Felix, I am not 100% sure how to iterate over the array as it differs in length each time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var item = [].concat(...Object.values(cities)).find(o => o.id == 2)
item && item.description
// => "This is another test"
```

If you will be looking up several different descriptions, as I stated in the comment, I'd prepare a lookup:

```
lookup = {}
Object.values(cities).forEach(a => a.forEach(e => lookup[e.id] = e))
lookup[2].description
// => "This is another test"
lookup[3].description
// => "This is a third test"
```

(Note that this answer uses ES6 syntax, but it is easy to convert to ES5 if you need older browser support.)

Comment: WOW! Nice one! thats unreal!

Comment: If you're writing ES6, why not `[].concat(...`?

Comment: @torazaburo: because derp :) Thanks. I haven't used all of it yet enough that using it comes natural, and old patterns peek their head.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is using JQuery

```
for (var city in cities) {
  if (cities.hasOwnProperty(city)) {
    $.each(cities[city] , function(i, item) {
       if(item.id == 1) {
           console.log(item.description);
       }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Where's the jQuery tag in this question?

Answer (score 0):

loop object with `for in` and loop array with `forEach`

```
function findById(d){
    var result;
    for(var k in cities){
                cities[k].forEach(function(v){
                     if(v.id == d) result = v.description;
                });
    }   
    return result;
} 
console.log(findById(5));
```